# bigstep package "maxp>= n is not true" error

Tags: r

I have a very big dataframe of 1000 columns and 1 million rows.

I want to make stepwise regression on it. And I want to use bigstep package.

```
library(bigstep)

data <- prepare_data(y, x)
```

here y is dependent variable and x is the rest 999 independent variables.
both of them are converted to matrix (as.matrix function) as stated in the package.

But I am getting that error

```
Error in create_parts(1:ncol(X), nrow(X))) : maxp >= is not TRUE
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it,

It happens when row num is too big.
when it is like that you have to set the function like that :

```
data <- prepare_data(y, x , maxp = a )
```

her a = a number greater than rownum of your dataframe

Thanks!